# Any characters not allowed in CSS stylesheet?

Tags: css

Long story short, I'm placing a bunch of css styles within a javascript variable and then dynamically injecting the css style node within the head element.  I'd like to encode a recurring container .someContainer ideally using one character and then do a search and replace within my javascript.  This would reduce my total css bytes by a bunch.  So i'm trying to figure out which character I would never come across in a stylesheet.    I can't think of when I've seen the ~ character in css and think it might be a good candidate.  Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tilde is a bad call for [two reasons](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors):

> `E[foo~="bar"]`
>   an E element whose "foo" attribute value is a list of whitespace-separated values, one of which is exactly equal to "bar"
>
> `E ~ F`
>   an F element preceded by an E element

You can't guarantee that anything else won't be used because of [`:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements:](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-CSS2-20090908/selector.html#before-and-after)

```
span:before {
    content: "anything is possible in here (or at zombo.com)";
}
```

You can run into similar issues with `url()`. You might be able to get away with `<` (but not `>`) but you'd still have the `content` problem with `:before` and `:after`.

You're probably better off setting everything up to use gzip compression for your stylesheets and possibly offloading it to a CDN.

Comment: thanks for the great explanation.  i'm going to go with a 2 character combination starting with < to reduce the likelihood of the pattern showing up within a :before or :after style.  and you're right, anything is possible at zombo.com!  :)